# GetTileID() Throwing array exception

Tags: java, arrays, bounds

I have a character in a game that I'm controlling, and I'm trying to use `getTileId()` to get the tile id of the tiles around him. I'm using the TilED map editor and slick2d. Heres my code:

```
int tileID = map.getTileId(idX, idY, 0);        
System.out.println("Id: "+tileID);
```

The map:

```
public TiledMap map;
```

Which is imported from:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;
```

`idX` and `idY` are set equal to zero and are the coordinates of my character. I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 188
at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.Layer.getTileID(Layer.java:137)
at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.getTileId(TiledMap.java:228)
at tile.Game.update(Game.java:144)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:657)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
```

I what the error means, but I have no idea why I'm getting it. I don't have a single array in my code right now. Can anyone give me some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that are both set to 0?  Your stack-trace seems to indicate otherwise.  Have you tried using `map.getTileId(0, 0, 0);` to see if that generates the same exception?

Comment: I updated the code to show the map.

Comment: aroth, that works fine, Its just whenever I use the players coordinates, it crashes. Does this mean its static? (Honestly don't know)

Comment: @opiop65 - It probably means that the player's coordinates are *not* `(0,0)`.  I would guess that they are set to some value that is outside of the coordinate-space of your in-game world.

Comment: Well its set to my player coordinates, which are always inside the map. I also found a weird issue with setting the parameters to more than (0, 30, 0). If y or x was higher than 30, it would crash and give me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java stack traces are so useful and so easy to understand that I can't explain your confusion. **You** don't use arrays, but the traces states that `map.getTileId()` calls `Layer.getTileID()` and it **does use arrays** ([link](https://bitbucket.org/liamzebedee/slick/src/e6fe92be50cc/trunk/Slick/src/org/newdawn/slick/tiled/Layer.java#cl-152) to the source):

```java
public int getTileID(int x, int y) {
        return data[x][y][2];
}
```

So either `idX` or `idY` holds `188` inside your call. We can't say **why** without accessing your full code, however there's an issue with your characeter: you *think* it's at  `(0, 0)` bun in fact it isn't. Maybe it's a race condition or API misusage, or objects badly initialized: we can't say, but at least you know where to look for.

Comment: Ok sorry, I never realized that it would use arrays. I'll post my full code later.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. However, I too had this problem, The way I fixed it was by dividing the player co-oridinates by the tile size because the map is an array of tiles.

example:

```
int tileID = map.getTileId(playerX / TILE_SIZE, playerY / TILE_SIZE, 0);
```